# How to animate circles in android

Tags: android, animation

I'm new to android and want to play a little with animation.
What I want to do:

[image: circles animation]

Each tiny circle should be clickable, and for now only number 2 can take 1's place and viceversa. I think I know how to draw the circle and positionate the tiny circles around it (I'm working on it :P) but I have no clue on how to implement the animation. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Whoa… This is an extensive subject.

Depending upon how you intend to draw your circles (I'd use a custom [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)), then you will probably want to create an [Animation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html) of some sort (possibly an [AnimationTranslation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html)).

You can even define those animations in XML, most likely in an [Animation Set](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html) so you can perform various actions in parallel.

That might be a starting point :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a value animator variable as global variable

```
ValueAnimator mValueAnimator = new ValueAnimator();
```

then add animation listener to the valueanimator.

```
mValueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    int angle = Integer.parseInt(animation.getAnimatedValue().toString());
                }
            });
```

Whenever you want to rotate the drawing or your custom view, I assume that you have used angles to rotate them.

So set the from angle and to angle to the animator.

```
mValueAnimator.setIntValues(fromAngle, toAngle);
```

Start the animation. It is better to check the animator is already running.

```
if (mValueAnimator.isRunning()) {
    mValueAnimator.end();
}
mValueAnimator.start();
```

Now you will get the animated value in onAnimationupdate() method of **AnimatorUpdateListener** you set to the value animator.

In this case the value is animated angle. Using the angle, animate the rotation.

Nobody likes linear animation. So try to use Interpolators.

```
mValueAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
```

you can use AccelerateInterpolator, OvershootInterpolator and so many.